# sending frames using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, frame

I've been asked to make a JAVA application for sending frames using sockets, my question is simple, is there anything special with this "frames"? i mean, i know how to transport bytes through net, I have knowledge about sockets, but I really don't know what are this frames , should i assume that by saying "frames" they are just referring to a specific structure of bytes to send?

they specify that the "frames" must have this structure:

- Header: E
- CRC: 8AFE
- Date: 110825080000
- Final Coin In: 2176
- Final Coin    Out: 12345
- Reserved: 0

so passing this to hex is

- 45
- 8A FE
- 31 31 30 38 32 35 30 38 30 30 30 30
- 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 31 37 36
- 30 30 30 30 30 31 32 33 34 35
- 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30

so if im correct, the frame (that i will convert to bytes later) to send is:

45 8A FE 31 31 30 38 32 35 30 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 31 37 36 30 30 30 30 3031 32 33 34 35 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30

My question is am I correct about this, or am I missing something? maybe i'm completely wrong? :s
Thanks in advance

PD: sorry if this is a dumb question :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java sockets API works at Layer 7.  You can send UDP packets or TCP/IP streams, but you *cannot* send or receive Ethernet frames with the standard Java.net package.

In other words, you can send and receive PAYLOADS, but you cannot read or write HEADERS (e.g. TCP-packet or Ethernet-frame headers).

At least not without writing your own JNI code, or using a 3rd party library for "raw sockets".  For example: https://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/

Comment: so, this 'frames' that i have to send are actually ethernet frames?

Comment: Maybe not.  *Hopefully* not.  Suggestion: ASK them: does their application write records consisting of: { Header: byte; Crc: short; Date: byte[12]; FinalCoinIn: byte[10]; FinalCountOut: byte[10]; Reserved: byte[10]};?  Are they fixed length, 45 byte records?  If "yes", then you should have no problem reading them with standard Java sockets.  You *DON'T* need to worry if your data is all Layer 7 (payload) data.

Comment: the frame consist in Header: 1 byte, CRC: 2 bytes, date: 12 bytes (...) everything is specified in bytes, maybe that means it is an ethernet frame? or that's not necessarily true?, thanks

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  Like I said above, you should ask.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't know what are this frames , should I assume

No. You should *ask* whoever gave you the requirement. Nobody wants guessing games.

EDIT: however, I will add two observations. First, the chances of anyone *ever* asking you to write out Ethernet frames directly in your entire career are vanishingly small. Second, that is not an Ethernet frame format, as even Google would have told you.

Comment: Some people - and i use the term loosely - would rather have guessing games than spend their oh-so-valuable time actually explaining what they want. However, these people should not be pandered to, so your advice stands.

Comment: @Tom Anderson yeah, and many people lately seem to prefer Google and questions on forums over clarifying the requirements at source.